# MailKit unable to authenticate IMAP

Tags: c#, office365, imap, mailkit

I have read every MailKit problem, but mine still will NOT work. I have removed my actual logins passwords, but they are correct for the account.

```
using (var client = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger(@"c:\temp\imaplog.txt")))
{
    try
    {
        client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, true);
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
        client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Clear();
        client.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls;
        client.Authenticate(<username>,<password>);
        //var inbox = client.mai;
        //inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        //var uids = await inbox.SearchAsync(MailKit.Search.SearchQuery.NotSeen);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
    }
}
```

IMAP logfile

```
Connected to imaps://outlook.office365.com:993/
S: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [UwBOADYAUABSADAAMQBDAEEAMAAwADAAMwAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBlAHgAYwBoAGEAbgBnAGUAbABhAGIAcwAuAGMAbwBtAA==]
C: A00000000 CAPABILITY
S: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
S: A00000000 OK CAPABILITY completed.
C: A00000001 LOGIN username password
S: A00000001 NO LOGIN failed.
```

Comment: Is MailKit sending the correct username and password strings to the server? Does your username include the `@domain` portion of the account email address? What if you try not including it or including it (i.e. do the opposite of what you are doing)? What happens if you remove `client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Clear();` to allow MailKit to use PLAIN authentication? Make sure to try with and without the `@domain` when testing with PLAIN as well.

Comment: I have tried everything you said, to no avail. If I include the domain, it would look like domain/username, password correct?

Comment: No, it would look like `username@outlook.com` or `username@office365.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your Office365 settings and make sure to allow IMAP logins via "less secure apps".

FYI: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/end-of-support-for-basic-authentication-access-to-exchange-online-apis-for-office-365-customers/

In other words, you'll need to start using XOAUTH2 by October 2020.